# Python TypeError when dividing a raw input variable by a number

Tags: python, typeerror

I want to convert an entered lb weight to kg and I get the following error...

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'unicode' and 'float'

My code:

```
lbweight = raw_input("Current Weight (lb): ") 

kgweight = lbweight/2.20462
```

Someone please help!

Comment: this mustn't be your real code, the error message doesn't match although it is almost the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raw_input` returns a string, you should convert the input to float using `float()`:

```
float(raw_input("Current Weight (lb): "))
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because with `raw_input`, the input is *raw*, meaning a string:

```
lbweight = float(raw_input("Current Weight (lb): ") )

kgweight = lbweight/2.20462
```

Comment: Is there a reason to attribute `raw` to a `string`?

Comment: @Abhijit yes, perhaps I need to be more specific though, updated

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the error message `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'`

```
>>> kgweight = lbweight/2.20462

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    kgweight = lbweight/2.20462
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'
>>>
```

So if 2.20462 is a float then which is a string here? What does the documentation say about [raw_input](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)?

> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output
>   without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input,
>   converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns
>   that. When EOF is read, EOFError is raised.